# How to cast a column from string to time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column with string values like

```
07:00 AM
10:00 AM
11:30 AM
12:30 PM
09:30 PM
```

Can anyone tell me, how can I cast this column into of Time type from String type.

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT CONVERT(time, TimeValue) FROM ...`?

Comment: Also you can use :   SELECT CAST('07:00 AM' AS  TIME);

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CAST(your_column_name AS TIME) from your_table_name
```